# How can I gain root access on a Mac OS X system without wiping the OS?

Tags: security, macos, root

My father died recently and I've inherited his Mac. I'd love to put it to use in my own life, but I don't want to wipe its brains out just so I can reconfigure it to use in my network, etc. His old files are historically important to me—I trust you can understand my desire to keep them.

I can log in as I had an account on the machine before he passed, but that's about it.

Answer (score 19):

Sincere condolences.

Try this: [Mac OS X - Resetting a Forgotten Account Password](http://kb.wisc.edu/helpdesk/page.php?id=3853)

The link shows a walk-through of starting up from the Mac OS X installation DVD and using its Reset Password functionality to reset the administrator account's password.

There's further information here: [Mac OS X: Changing or resetting an account password](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1274)

Answer (score 6):

If you don't want to make any changes to the mac, a little known feature called [Target Disk Mode](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1661) might make it easier.

Answer (score 4):

If your account is an administrator account.  You can open up Terminal.app and type

```
sudo passwd root
```

You will be prompted to enter a new root password.

If you don't have administrator access, you can reset the root password using your osx installation cd.  Instructions are [here](http://www.askdavetaylor.com/how_do_i_reset_my_mac_os_x_admin_root_password.html).

EDIT: [Node](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7190/node)'s [link](http://kb.wisc.edu/helpdesk/page.php?id=3853) is better.

Answer (score 4):

If open firmware password has not been set, you can try entering single user mode by pressing apple-s during boot. Then you should be able to do anything you want, since you will be root.

See [this apple support document](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1492).

I recommend using this capability to make all your father's files readable by your normal user account, then backup all his files and do a fresh reinstall.

Comment: Booting single-user doesn't make it all that easy to reset passwords, as passwords are stored in NetInfo (10.4 and earlier) or Open Directory (10.5).

Comment: No, but it does make it easy to change the file permissions so the files are accessible then. This allows them to be backed up and then the OS reinstalled without loss of data.

Answer (score 2):

Boot the computer with a BSD or Linux CD and mount the filesystem.

Comment: I loove Knoppix for that, if nothing else :-)

Answer (score 1):

If the machine is running leopard or higher you can actually force
   any mac to create a new administrator account by simply deleting one file.

- Simply boot into single user mode, (hold `command` + `s` when booting up)
- once in single user mode, mount the file system using `mount -uw /`
- then input `rm /var/db/.AppleSetupDone`
- restart the machine.

  This works by removing the check `.AppleSetupDone` so it tricks the
  mac into replaying the setup assistant on boot.

---

**Else**, you can do something very similar to older macs by again booting up into single user mode, except this time inputting the following (line by line)

```
mount -uw /
cd /private/var/db/netinfo
mv local.nidb local.old
rm ../.AppleSetupDone
exit
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can access the files in question, then the first thing to do would be to back them up...

Answer (score 0):

FWIW

assuming your account has admin privileges, boot the machine and enter your password; then use the Finder to navigate to his user folder (/Users/*name-he-used-on-the-mac*); his subfolders will have a little red locked symbol.

you can either copy/paste them in the finder (you will be prompted for your password), or

you can open terminal and ditto them:

```
      sudo ditto <his files> <directory where you want the copies>
```

at which time you will be prompted for *your* password.